# GoReleaser cross compilation fails

Tags: go, cross-compiling, goreleaser

I'm trying to release my project in both `linux` and `windwos` machines without success.

I have tried to explicitly define the `-CC` to few options but non of them worked in both machines.

Pre installed packages:

sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib g++-multilib
sudo apt-get install gcc-mingw-w64

In the project i'm using `c` code which uses these `flags` in order to selective compilation

```
//#cgo windows CFLAGS: "-IC:/Program Files/OpenSSL-Win64/include"
//#cgo windows LDFLAGS: "-LC:/Program Files/OpenSSL-Win64/lib" -llibcrypto
//#cgo linux LDFLAGS: -lssl -lcrypto
//#cgo CFLAGS: -Wno-deprecated-declarations
```

running GoRelaser locally on `windows` machine will result this error.

```
  ⨯ release failed after 24.28s error=failed to build for windows_arm64: exit status 2: # runtime/cgo
gcc_arm64.S: Assembler messages:
gcc_arm64.S:28: Error: no such instruction: `stp x29,x30,[sp,'
gcc_arm64.S:32: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
gcc_arm64.S:34: Error: no such instruction: `stp x19,x20,[sp,'
gcc_arm64.S:37: Error: no such instruction: `stp x21,x22,[sp,'
gcc_arm64.S:40: Error: no such instruction: `stp x23,x24,[sp,'
gcc_arm64.S:43: Error: no such instruction: `stp x25,x26,[sp,'
gcc_arm64.S:46: Error: no such instruction: `stp x27,x28,[sp,'
gcc_arm64.S:50: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
gcc_arm64.S:51: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
gcc_arm64.S:52: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
gcc_arm64.S:54: Error: no such instruction: `blr x20'
gcc_arm64.S:55: Error: no such instruction: `blr x19'
gcc_arm64.S:57: Error: no such instruction: `ldp x27,x28,[sp,'
gcc_arm64.S:60: Error: no such instruction: `ldp x25,x26,[sp,'
gcc_arm64.S:63: Error: no such instruction: `ldp x23,x24,[sp,'
gcc_arm64.S:66: Error: no such instruction: `ldp x21,x22,[sp,'
gcc_arm64.S:69: Error: no such instruction: `ldp x19,x20,[sp,'
gcc_arm64.S:72: Error: no such instruction: `ldp x29,x30,[sp],'

    ⨯ release failed after 24.28s error=failed to build for windows_arm64: exit status 2: # runtime/cgo
gcc_arm64.S: Assembler messages:
gcc_arm64.S:28: Error: no such instruction: `stp x29,x30,[sp,'
gcc_arm64.S:32: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
gcc_arm64.S:34: Error: no such instruction: `stp x19,x20,[sp,'
gcc_arm64.S:37: Error: no such instruction: `stp x21,x22,[sp,'
gcc_arm64.S:40: Error: no such instruction: `stp x23,x24,[sp,'
gcc_arm64.S:43: Error: no such instruction: `stp x25,x26,[sp,'
gcc_arm64.S:46: Error: no such instruction: `stp x27,x28,[sp,'
gcc_arm64.S:50: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
gcc_arm64.S:51: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
gcc_arm64.S:52: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
gcc_arm64.S:54: Error: no such instruction: `blr x20'
gcc_arm64.S:55: Error: no such instruction: `blr x19'
gcc_arm64.S:57: Error: no such instruction: `ldp x27,x28,[sp,'
gcc_arm64.S:60: Error: no such instruction: `ldp x25,x26,[sp,'
gcc_arm64.S:63: Error: no such instruction: `ldp x23,x24,[sp,'
gcc_arm64.S:66: Error: no such instruction: `ldp x21,x22,[sp,'
gcc_arm64.S:69: Error: no such instruction: `ldp x19,x20,[sp,'
gcc_arm64.S:72: Error: no such instruction: `ldp x29,x30,[sp],'
```

running GoReleaser locally on `ubuntu` machine will result

```
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mthreads’; did you mean ‘-pthread’?
```

GoReleaser:

```
# This is an example .goreleaser.yml file with some sensible defaults.
# Make sure to check the documentation at https://goreleaser.com
before:
  hooks:
    # You may remove this if you don't use go modules.
    - go mod tidy
    # you may remove this if you don't need go generate
    - go generate ./...
builds:
  - env:
      - CGO_ENABLED=1
    goos:
      - linux
      - windows
archives:
  - replacements:
      linux: Linux
      windows: Windows
      386: i386
      amd64: x86_64
checksum:
  name_template: 'checksums.txt'
snapshot:
  name_template: "{{ incpatch .Version }}-next"
changelog:
  sort: asc
  filters:
    exclude:
      - '^docs:'
      - '^test:'
```

Answer (score 1):

By [default](https://goreleaser.com/customization/build/#builds) GoReleaser will attempt to make builds for 386, amd64 and arm64. But your windows machine is likey an amd64/x86_64 machine. Normally this is no issue with Go, but since you are using CGO your C toolchain has to support compilation for arm64, which it doesn't.

You should be able to limit the CPU architectures it attempts to build by adding `goarch` to your config file:

```yaml
...
builds:
  goarch:
    - amd64
...
```

Cross compiling cgo projects is notoriously difficult and a known [limitation](https://goreleaser.com/limitations/cgo/) of GoReleaser. I recommend taking a look at the [cgo cookbook](https://goreleaser.com/cookbooks/cgo-and-crosscompiling/) if you have not already done so.

As for the error you are getting on ubuntu, it looks like you C toolchain doesn't have the right dependencies/capabilities to cross compile to windows.

I have not done any CGO cross compilation myself(attempt to avoid it at all costs) so I can't vouch for this tool, but from what I am reading online [xgo](https://github.com/karalabe/xgo) might be able to help you out.